# how to call another method in C# from another file

Tags: c#, web-services, ssis

I have tried looking through many sources, but I just do not understand what needs to be done as I am not a C# developer. The only reason I have been assigned this project is because the web services we need to connect to apparently is only compatible in C#. So I am just learning as I go trying to get this project done. And no one else in our dept. knows C#. 
I am building a SSIS package, and have a "Script Task" using C#. The scriptMain.cs which the tool creates is this

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ST_3c3fd2f1b7404161b62ff2b81f12192c.ServiceClient;

namespace ST_3c3fd2f1b7404161b62ff2b81f12192c.csproj
{
[System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
public partial class ScriptMain :     Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{

    public void MainScript()
    {
        // TODO: Add your code here
        Program.Main();//I AM TRYING TO MAKE THE CALL TO PROGRAM.cs file Main() method
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
}
}
```

I guess this ScriptMain.cs is the file that gets executed when I run the SSIS. So I am trying to make a call from scriptMain.cs (Program.Main()) from above to file Program.cs below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ST_3c3fd2f1b7404161b62ff2b81f12192c.ServiceClient;
using ST_3c3fd2f1b7404161b62ff2b81f12192c.csproj;

namespace ST_3c3fd2f1b7404161b62ff2b81f12192c
{
class Program
{
    static void Main()//Trying to call this so that it can execute its   methods/processes
    {
        WebClient client = GetClient();

        // Example 1 - Select Changes
        SelectTicketChanges(client);
        SelectStepChanges(client);
    }
```

As you can see this Main() method calls other methods. I did not write this BTW, it was provided by the client who we are trying to connect to.

Right now, Program.Main(), Main() has red error underneath saying
"Program.Main() is inaccessible due to its protection level"

If I change

```
 static void Main()
```

to

```
 public void Main()
```

than my ScriptMain.cs Program.Main() all gets Red Error underneath saying 
"An Object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.."

I just want it to call that other method, so that it can do its function.

If you could be as little as technical as you can be that would be really great. As I have said I'm just learnin C# as I go through this project.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to:

```
public static void Main()
```

In short, this is because `static` needs to stay.

To give a bit more detail: the default accessibility for methods is `private`, so the existing method is equivalent to `private static void Main()`. This should change to `public` so that you can call it from your class `ScriptMain`.

The `static` means that it belongs to the class `Program`, and can be called as `Program.Main()`, not to an instance, which would mean it could only be called from an instance, e.g. `new Program().Main()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

When executing a program written in C#, the CLR searches for a static method marked with the .entrypoint IL directive, which takes either no arguments, or a single argument of type string[], and has a return type of void or int, and executes it

so what ever you have to do you have to call it inside Static main function

Comment: The code snippet given to the OP might *also* contain the entry point for one of the vendor's code samples, but the question has nothing to do with entry points. In this situation, `Main` is a perfectly ordinary method that the OP is trying to call from another method.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to look up OO (Object Oriented) programming and C# in general. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/219869/Object-Oriented-Programming-in-Csharp-NET

But to answer your question, if you want to access static methods reference their class and then them, for example:

```
Program.Main();
```

To access non-static methods you have to instantiate an object("class" to be more exact) first, example:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.Method();
```

Append: You might have trouble compiling/running that code because visual studio thinks that `Program.Main()` is the entry point for the program (even though this is not the case) You need to tell the compiler that actually `ScriptMain.MainScript()` is the entry point by looking in your solution properties.

Comment: You can't name it `class`, since that's a reserved keyword. You could use e.g. `@class` or `myClass`.

Comment: Or even better, use the names already in the OP's code snippet.

Comment: I didn't want to use `Program x = new Program();` since it's quite misleading.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
public static void Main()
{
}
```